# Jquery: Replace value of input A by value of input B when clicking on checkbox

Tags: jquery

I want to replace the value (text) of "input2" by the value of "input1" when I check the checkbox

here my code:

```
$("#check").click(function () {

$('#input2').html($('#input1').val());

});


<input type="text" id="input2">

<input type="checkbox" id="check">

<input type="text" id="input1">
```

For the moment, it's only working if "input2" is a div and not an input.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.val()` to set the value of an input not `.html()`

```
$('#input2').val($('#input1').val());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `attr` or `val` method to update value of input element.

```
$("#check").click(function () {
    $('#input2').attr('value',$('#input1').val());
});​
```

or

```
$("#check").click(function () {
    $('#input2').val($('#input1').val());
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lp8dY/